# xml xpath read big file, from one part to other

Tags: php, xpath

I have very long xml file, like this:

```
<cars>
    <car>
        <name>Ford</name>
        <number>F33</number>
        <color>Blue</color>
    </car>
    <car>
        <name>Ford</name>
        <number>F43</number>
        <color>Red</color>
    </car>
    <car>
        <name>Ford</name>
        <number>F53</number>
        <color>Red</color>
    </car>  
    <car>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <number>A001</number>
        <color>Red</color>
    </car>
    <car>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <number>A032</number>
        <color>White</color>
    </car>
       .......
</cars>
```

How with php xpath read from one part to ather.

For example like sql LIMIT 10, 30
show elemens from 10 to 30

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a one-liner XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted elements. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How with php xpath read from one part
>   to ather.
>
> For example like sql LIMIT 10, 30 show
>   elemens from 10 to 30

**Use**:

```
/*/car[position() > 9 and not(position() > 30)]
```

Comment: Thanks ;) but maybe there is and some ORDER function?

Comment: @lolalola: Sorry, couldn't understand your comment. Could you explain, please?